# Why does the selected data miss some rows when using lock in share mode?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking

I have a table A:

```
create table A(id int(11) auto_increment primary key, name varchar(255));
```

And 
I have many threads are doing following two transaction simultaneously:

```
TRANSACTION 1:
SELECT id, name FROM A (SQL1)
SELECT id, name FROM A WHERE id > ? LOCK IN SHARE MODE (SQL2) 

TRANSACTION 2:
INSERT INTO A(name) VALUES (?) (SQL3)
```

I find a stange thing:

> Sometimes, not always, SQL2's result miss some rows

For example:

SQL1's result is:

```
(1, "a")
(2, "b")
(3, "c")
```

but SQL2's result is :

```
(1, "a")
(2, "b")
```

It can not see (3, "c"), There is no other SQL to delete table's rows;

Why?

My mysqld version is 5.6.22, the engine is InnoDB

Comment: I assume you didn't change the isolation level and it is still 'REPEATABLE-READ '?

Comment: Yes, it is "REPEATABLE-READ"